# How correctly specify the textarea width? Using the cols attribute I obtain different width using different browser

Tags: html, css, xhtml, textarea

I have some problem with the definition of the width of a **textarea**

So, I have this situation:

```
<div id="dialogReject" title="">
    <table style="visibility: hidden;" id="rifiutaTable" border="0" class="standard-table-cls" style="width: 100%!important">

        <tbody style="background-color: #ffffff;">
            <tr>
                <td style="font: 16px Verdana,Geneva,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif !important">Inserire note di rifiuto</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <textarea style="visibility: hidden;" rows="5" cols="70" id="myRejectNote"></textarea>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input class="bottone" readonly="readonly" type="text" value="Rifiuta" onclick="rifiuta()"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</div>
```

The div having **id="dialogReject"** represent a JQuery dialog in which there is a **textarea**, this one:

```
<textarea style="visibility: hidden;" rows="5" cols="70" id="myRejectNote"></textarea>
```

So, as you can see, the width of this **textarea** is specified by its columns number: **cols="70"**

Actually the columns number is setted on 70 and it is good for **FireFox**, infact this is the obtained result:

[image]

and it is ok, but when I try to open it on **Explorer** I obtain:

[image]

As you can see using only 70 columns don't fill all the horizontal space into my dialog (I have to increase to 100 columns, but in this way go out of the dialog when I use FireFox)

How can I solve this problem? Can I specify the textarea width in some different way so it is correctly rendered for all the browser?

Tnx

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai Tnx, it works...if you post it as answer I will accept it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply `width:100%` for `textarea`

```
 <textarea style="visibility: hidden; width:100%;" rows="5" cols="70" id="myRejectNote"></textarea>
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/ksdaL9a7/)

Answer (score 0):

`cols` is useful if you want all browsers to display the same number of characters in the textarea. That way, the user experience is the same, even if the number of pixels that the textarea takes up is different.
As an example, paste an 80 character string into the textarea. With a width in `cols`, it will look the same everywhere, but with only a forced width of `100%`, one browser will put the string on one line, while the other needs two lines.

The solution, therefore, is to not simply force the width to `100%`, but to specify the font used in the textarea explicitly, both family and size. That way, you can be assured that the result looks the same everywhere.